# Android Room @RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns not working

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Dao query with table joins:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM t_work t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT *, max(gmt_create) FROM t_work_log GROUP BY work_id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.work_id;")
  fun getWorkAndLog(): Flow<Map<Work, WorkLog>>
```

Unable to complete the build, it reports the following error:

```
E:\AndroidProjects\MyApplication\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\release\com\freedom\android\work\dao\IWorkDao.java:15:
The query returns some columns [max(gmt_create)] which are not used by any of [`Work`,`WorkLog`]
```

Different solutions were then prompted:

1. You can use `@ColumnInfo` annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.
2. You can annotate the method with `@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns` to direct Room to rewrite your query to avoid fetching unused columns.
3. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with `@SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH)`.

I don't think any of the three solutions are ideal for me, but I'd like to try the second one and see what happens with the so-called rewrite.

```kotlin
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
  @Query("SELECT * FROM t_work t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT *, max(gmt_create) FROM t_work_log GROUP BY work_id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.work_id;")
  fun getWorkAndLog(): Flow<Map<Work, WorkLog>>
```

But it doesn't work, I still can't build, it still reports `The query returns some columns`, What I did wrong?

About Room's dependencies:

```kotlin
def room_version = "2.5.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// To use Coroutine features, you must add `ktx` artifact from Room as a dependency. androidx.room:room-ktx:<version>
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
// optional - Paging 3 Integration
implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version"
```

Is it the best option to ignore this warning for this situation?

I think `max(gmt_create)` exists only for this function and it should not be added to the persistence class. Leave it to Room to rewrite the query sql, although I haven't seen the results yet, I think this rewrite might change my intentions.

---

First Edit:

After I close Android Studio and open it again, this compilation error disappears. So this could be a problem with Android Studio or Gradle? But this error will appear again from time to time.

It's tricky, and I can't fully reproduce the problem, which only comes up occasionally.

Comment: A fourth option is to only specify the required output columns. Using `SELECT * ....` will select all columns in the table. Whilst `SELECT cola, colb ....` will select just those 2 columns.

Comment: @MikeT `max(gmt_create)` is required, in a sense it is a query condition.

Answer (score 1):

> The query returns some columns [max(gmt_create)] which are not used by any of [`Work`,`WorkLog`]

and

> max(gmt_create) is required, in a sense it is a query condition

It is not required in the output columns though AND as the warning says Room does not need it and ignores it.

- *Perhaps the warning message should be along the lines of "Why are you telling me to work out this value for you to simply throw the value in the bin"*

Now if instead of using the max function, you were to use the sum/total function then the result would not be as expected and would highlight the underlying flaw.

To demonstrate a **Work** object has the fields/columns

- id
- name
- other
- etc

and the **WorkFlow** object has the fields(columns)

- id
- work_id
- gmt_create
- another
- blah

So the following will create the 2 tables and load some data into them, using an SQLite tool (rather than writing all the code in a demo App)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_work (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, other TEXT, etc TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_work_log (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, work_id INTEGER, gmt_create INTEGER, another TEXT, blah TEXT);

INSERT INTO t_work VALUES 
    (1,'w1','otherw1','etcw1'),
    (2,'w2','otherw2','etcw2'),
    (3,'w3','otherw3','etcw3')
;
INSERT INTO t_work_log (work_id,gmt_create,another,blah) VALUES
    (1,10,900,'blah for w1-10-900')
    ,(1,11,901,'blah for w1-11-901')
    ,(1,8,902,'blah for w1-8-902')
    ,(1,7,903,'blah for w1-7-903')
    ,(1,12,904,'blah for w1-12-904')
    ,(1,1,905,'blah for w1-1-905')
    ,(1,21,906,'blah for w1-21-906')
    ,(1,6,907,'blah for w1-6-907')
    ,(2,111,801,'blah for w2-111-801')
    ,(2,18,802,'blah for w2-18-802')
    ,(2,17,803,'blah for w2-17-803')
    ,(2,112,804,'blah for w2-112-804')
    ,(2,11,805,'blah for w2-11-805')
    ,(2,121,806,'blah for w2-121-806')
    ,(2,16,807,'blah for w2-16-807')
    ,(3,211,701,'blah for w3-211-701')
    ,(3,28,702,'blah for w3-28-702')
    ,(3,27,703,'blah for w3-27-703')
    ,(3,212,704,'blah for w3-27-704')
    ,(3,21,705,'blah for w3-21-705')
    ,(3,221,706,'blah for w3-221-706')
    ,(3,26,707,'blah for w3-26-707')
;
```

Now your query **`SELECT * FROM t_work t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT *, max(gmt_create) FROM t_work_log GROUP BY work_id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.work_id;`** results in :-

[image]

Room will do it's stuff, IGNORING, the max(gmt_create) column, and using the apparently correct value from the gmt_create column to assign a value to the gmt_create field. Other than the warning nothing untoward happens.

Now if the query were ***`SELECT * FROM t_work t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT *, sum(gmt_create) FROM t_work_log GROUP BY work_id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.work_id;`*** the result would be:-

[image]

The **gmt_create** column and the sum(gmt_create) differ, Room will assign the gmt_create column's value to the gmt_create field and the flaw will be noticable.

The options to avoid the warning AND to correctly get the derived value should be to either

- a) Use a POJO that has a field that Room will assigned the derived value to (e.g. a field name `max(gmt_create)`).

  - in which case your query would be fine.
- b) Have the query manipulate the values to produce output with suitable columns and values that will allow Room to assign appropriate values according to the requirements.

  - in which case the query based upon the demo could be *`SELECT t1.*,t2.id,t2.work_id,t2.[max(gmt_create)] AS gmt_create,t2.another,t2.blah FROM t_work t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT *, max(gmt_create) FROM t_work_log GROUP BY work_id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.work_id;`*

The latter query would output:-

[image]

If using sum instead of max then it would output:-

[image]

i.e. it is a) clear that the derived values have been placed into the gmt_create column ADN that the extraneous column has not been output, thus avoiding the warning and any need to suppress the warning.

- But note that then another factor is highlighted and that is that arbitrary values are assigned to other columns in a group.

  - see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#generation_of_the_set_of_result_rows

---

**Additional**

---

re:-

> After reading your answer, the best option in my case would have been to simply ignore the warning. But I'm curious about the @RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns documentation that says annotation will cause Room to rewrite your Query methods, how is it rewritten? Does it just remove max(gmt_create) from my sql statement? This will result in incorrect query results.

1. Simplest is to ignore the warning.
2. According to a simple testRegarding the rest does it re-write the query BUT by embedding the original query as a subquery.

Consider:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT *, 'useless data' AS useless_column FROM job")
fun getAllJobsEtcWithUselessData(): List<JobWithWorkersAndPosterWithPosterWorker>
```

and thus:-

```
warning: The query returns some columns [useless_column] which are not used by a.a.so75656155kotlinroomrelationships.JobWithWorkersAndPosterWithPosterWorker. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. You can annotate the method with @RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns to direct Room to rewrite your query to avoid fetching unused columns.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: job_id, jobName, useless_column.
public abstract java.util.List<a.a.so75656155kotlinroomrelationships.JobWithWorkersAndPosterWithPosterWorker> getAllJobsEtcWithUselessData();
```

The generated java (in the java(generated) from Android View) includes:-

```
  @Override
  public List<JobWithWorkersAndPosterWithPosterWorker> getAllJobsEtcWithUselessData() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT *, 'useless data' AS useless_column FROM job";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
  ....
```

Change to add the @Rewrite.... :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT *, 'useless data' AS useless_column FROM job")
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
fun getAllJobsEtcWithUselessData(): List<JobWithWorkersAndPosterWithPosterWorker>
```

The warning is gone and the generated java is now :-

```
  @Override
  public List<JobWithWorkersAndPosterWithPosterWorker> getAllJobsEtcWithUselessData() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT `job_id`, `jobName` FROM (SELECT *, 'useless data' AS useless_column FROM job)";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
  ....
```

Actually quite a nice little trick. HOWEVER, as explained re sum v max the actual derived value is not available/used.

Now if you still have concerns, then you can do away with the `@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns` by:-

1. Include the annotation appropriately.
2. Compile.
3. Go to the java (generated)
4. Find the class that is the same name as the respective @Dao annotated interface/abstract class but suffixed with **Impl**
5. search for the function, the adjusted SQL can then be used to do what Room does and that is embed the original query as a subquery, and have the overall query only extract the required columns.

Comment: After reading your answer, the best option in my case would have been to simply ignore the warning. But I'm curious about the `@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns` documentation that says `annotation will cause Room to rewrite your Query methods`, how is it rewritten? Does it just remove `max(gmt_create)` from my sql statement? This will result in incorrect query results.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt after a very quick look. The answer has been updated (@Rewrite doesn't just remove it, it hides it from view).

Comment: So in my case, it won't affect the original query result? Sorry, the reason why I'm not sure about the result is because I can't reproduce the problem anymore, Room doesn't report an error, so `@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns` won't change my sql statement either.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I know how to find the statements generated by Room. But in my project Room doesn't detect the `column not use` error, so the `impl` type sql statement generated by Room is not modified, it's not different from the original sql statement. So I really just want to know that in my case, `@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns` doesn't change my original sql statement, it just wraps a layer on the outside, right?

Answer (score 0):

I  This query

```
SELECT * FROM t_work t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT *, max(gmt_create) FROM t_work_log GROUP BY work_id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.work_id;
```

have a syntax error.
Try it

```
SELECT * FROM t_work t1 INNER JOIN 
( SELECT work_id, MAX(gmt_create) Amax_gmt_create FROM t_work_logGROUP BY work_id)
t2 ON t1.id = t2.work_id;
```